# Cannot enable VMware EVC for Xeon E5-2630v3 (Haswell) on vSphere 6.0

Tags: vmware-vsphere, dell-poweredge, vmware-vcenter, xeon, vmotion

I've got two DELL PowerEdge R730 servers loaded with a dual Xeon E5-2630v3 Haswell. When I installed VMware vCenter, I tried to create a Cluster with VMware vMotion EVC mode set to Haswell, since it's a Haswell chip, but VMware complains about the CPU being incompatible.

The error message that I've got is the following:

> The host's CPU hardware should support the cluster's current Enhanced
>   vMotion Compatibility mode, but some of the necessary CPU features are
>   missing from the host. Check the host's BIOS configuration to ensure
>   that no necessary features are disabled (such as XD, VT, AES, or
>   PCLMULQDQ for Intel, or NX for AMD). For more information, see KB
>   article 1003212.

I even looked at the official VMware documentation ([Here](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=1003212&sliceId=2&docTypeID=DT_KB_1_1&dialogID=573976660&stateId=0%200%20573978899) and [here](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1034926)) without any success. Since, as today, vSphere 6.0 is simply too new, there isn't familiar cases to look around.

On the BIOS basic things like VT-x, VT-d and AES are enabled. The only disabled things are: "Logical Processor Idling" and "X2APIC Mode".

Comment: Do you need to enable EVC?

Comment: At this moment, no. I was just doing the service and wanted to do the best possible. Anyway I can enable it at Ivy Bridge level.

Comment: Were you able to overcome this issue? I'm trying to install 64-bit Windows  on my 64-bit Host and I have this same problem. I have an HP Z440 configured with the same E5 2630v3. I checked the BIOS too and that's got VT-X enabled. I used Intel's Identification Utility and that mentions VtX is supported. Does not say enabled or disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure Intel No-Execute (XD) is enabled

It's also possible a BIOS update can help make sure the compatible version of Streaming SIMD Extensions (SSE) for both hosts.